# Use Contains() extension method on arrays in C#

Tags: c#, extension-methods, ienumerable

There is a Contains() extension method on IEnumerable; In VB I am able to do this:

```
If New String() {"A", "B"}.Contains("B") Then
    ' ...
End If
```

What would be the equivalent of this in C#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the same idea in C#, using LINQ extension methods:

```
using System.Linq;
...

if (new string[] {"A", "B"}.Contains("B")) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I knew it was that simple, the real problem was I tried this on an Empty Website Project and was missing a reference to System.Data.Linq. Thanks.

Comment: How do you do this these days (1/19/2018) if you don't wish to use Linq? I tried creating an extension method, but kept failing, because I've never done that before.